# monitor resolution reseted after reboot (one monitor)

Tags: drivers, display, monitor, xrandr, display-resolution

I have a computer with ONLY ONE MONITOR - these are the specs:

```
Ubuntu 15.04 - 32 bits
Processor Intel® Pentium(R) Dual CPU E2180 @ 2.00GHz × 2  
Graphics Intel® G33 x86/MMX/SSE2
```

```
$ lspci -v | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

```
# lshw -class display
```

```
PCI (sysfs)  
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 10
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:28 memory:feb00000-feb7ffff ioport:e140(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fe900000-fe9fffff
```

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```
$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
$ sudo xrandr --addmode VGA1 1680x1050_60.00 
$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm

   1680x1050      60.0*+
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
   1680x1050_60.00   60.0  

VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

This works (changes the resolution), then I do

```
$ sudo reboot
```

and on start I get the previous resolution and the following message

```
No se pudo aplicar la configuración almacenada para los monitores
none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:
Trying modes for CRTC 63 CRTC 63:
trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 800x600@56Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 848x480@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 800x600@56Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 848x480@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
Trying modes for CRTC 64
CRTC 64: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 800x600@56Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 848x480@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 800x600@56Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 848x480@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 64: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
Trying modes for CRTC 65
CRTC 65: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 800x600@56Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 848x480@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 65: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 800x600@56Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 848x480@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 65: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1680x1050@60Hz (pass 1)
```

Comment: also, does anyone think this problem could go away if I change the graphic card to a better one? Thanks!!!

Comment: Intel core 2 duo graphics are a nightmare to get as you want them. I actually had almost exactly the same specs as you and I had to use xrandr - I also got this error. If you get an NVidia card - such as a Geforce 210 (£20), you'll find it loads easier to set your desired resolution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `xrandr` configurations to a startup file, so that you'll get your desired resolution upon reboot/startup:

- Create a bash script, `xrandr.sh` for example, and place your xrandr commands into it:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1680x1050_60.00 
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1680x1050_60.00
```

- Make the script executable with `chmod +x xrandr.sh`
- Search for "Startup Applications" in the dash, run it, and add the script as a startup application.

The commands will now run every time you log into your account.

Comment: hi, DevRobot. Thanks for answering so promptly. I tried that solution and it works. I don't have to copy/paste the commands every time I turn the computer on. But I humbly believe there must be a way of achieving this without having the computer trying something and failing and trying it again. Here's a screenshot o how it looks on startup and the xrandr output  ![Screenshot](http://s12.postimg.org/mu9do3o18/Captura_de_pantalla_de_2015_10_06_09_47_06.jpg) . Isn't there a better way of having your optimal and desired screen resolution? Thanks!!!

Comment: @TabulaRasa first of all, did you use `cvt 1680 1050` to determine the exact newmode line required?

Comment: @TabulaRasa this is one of the solutions for getting a permanent xrandr configuration - but if you have an NVidia card, you can install the required driver and get a better solution

Comment: The arandr pacakage has a an obscure but nice command line utility also called unxrandr which can get the xrandr command to make your current display and then put that in the script and autostart it.